# How to find the list of tab names in actively opened browser using python script

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to list down the all tab titles in already opened browser.

I have used Python and selenium webdriver package but it is creating a new browser session and listing out the tab names instead of listing from already opened browser

I have tried with Python 3.7 version and selenium package

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdrive
path=r"C:\Windows\chromedriver"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path)
browser.get('https://www.google.com?q=python#q=python')
length=len(driver.window_handles)
titles=[]
for i in range(length):
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i])
titles.append(driver.title)
print(title)
```

I am expecting the output in already opened browser not from newly created one.

Answer (score 1):

The follow give you the title of most active tab of the first or only one opened firefox browser, by python.

```
import subprocess  
wins = subprocess.run('wmctrl -l', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
title = next(ln for ln in wins.stdout.decode('utf-8').splitlines() if 'Mozilla Firefox' in ln)
print title
```

Answer (score 0):

It is **impossible** to do. There is already couple of opened issues about this feature in selenium's github page and all of them are closed.

[Example issue](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/18)

Answer (score 0):

One alternate way is to get the titles of browser tab by bash on follow way:

```
browser=Firefox
page_title=$(wmctrl -l -p | grep "$browser")
echo "$page_title"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate to your asked way by python, you can do it:

```
by copy and past by hand
by Brotab
by Selenium
by xdotool
by javascript from serversite or by code injection from client side
```